# Don't show component if the width is too narrow

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Is that possible in React to calculate the width of a component and if the width is too narrow, don't show it?

If possible can this be achieved in the first render so the implementation is not ugly.

Comment: A CSS media query would be a better fit.

Comment: But if the width of the component is dynamic, I don't think CSS media query can work

Answer (score 0):

Using DOM element to handle some UI calculations it sounds like bad practice. I'm sure that you can predict width based on passed data.

For example, you may decide to hide some components when some passed data too short, like this:

```
const Foo = ({ heading }) => {
  if (heading.length < 10) return null;

  return <h1>{heading}</h1>;
};
```